How can I store real-time WhatsApp messages in a Google Sheet using Laravel and the Meta for Developers API?
I am working on a project where I need to receive WhatsApp messages in real time using the Meta for Developers API. I want to capture these messages and automatically store them in a Google Sheet.
I have the following setup:
Laravel framework to handle backend and frontend functionality.
Meta for Developers API for sending/receiving WhatsApp messages.
I want to:
Capture real-time WhatsApp messages.
Store these messages in a Google Sheet automatically as they come in.
Ensure that the stored data includes useful details such as:
The sender's phone number.
The message content.
Timestamp.

share something which you tried but not working. You will not get whole code from here by just post your requirement.

Your question is too broad. You should start by showing examples of what you have tried.
However, here is an example:
To achieve this setup, you will need to integrate the Meta for Developers API with Laravel and set up Google Sheets API to store the received messages.
Step 1: Set Up Meta for Developers API
Create a Meta App:

Go to the Meta for Developers website and create a new app.
Add the "WhatsApp" product to your app.

Configure Webhooks:

Set up a webhook to receive real-time notifications of incoming messages.
In the webhook configuration, specify the URL of your Laravel endpoint that will handle incoming messages.

Step 2: Laravel Backend to Handle Incoming Messages

Create a Route and Controller:
Define a route in routes/web.php to handle the webhook.

Route::post('/webhook/whatsapp','WhatsAppController@handleIncomingMessage');

Create a WhatsAppController with a method to handle the incoming message.
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Sheets;

class WhatsAppController extends Controller
{
    public function handleIncomingMessage(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        // Extract necessary details
        $senderPhoneNumber = $data['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['from'];
        $messageContent = $data['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['text']['body'];
        $timestamp = $data['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['timestamp'];

        // Store data in Google Sheets
        $this->storeInGoogleSheets($senderPhoneNumber, $messageContent, $timestamp);

        return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
    }

    // refactor, move out of the controller to a service
    private function storeInGoogleSheets($phoneNumber, $message, $timestamp)
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API Integration');
        $client->setScopes([Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
        $client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('app/google-sheets-credentials.json'));
        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
        $spreadsheetId = 'your-spreadsheet-id';
        $range = 'Sheet1!A:C';

        $values = [
            [
                $phoneNumber,
                $message,
                date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)
            ],
        ];

        $body = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
            'values' => $values
        ]);

        $params = [
            'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
        ];

        $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
    }
}

Step 3: Set Up Google Sheets API
Enable Google Sheets API:

Go to the Google Cloud Console, create a new project or use an existing one.
Enable the Google Sheets API for your project.

Create Service Account:

Create a service account in your Google Cloud project and download the credentials JSON file.
Place the credentials file in your Laravel project's storage/app directory.

Share Google Sheet with Service Account:

Open your Google Sheet, click on "Share", and share it with the email address of the service account.

Step 4: Test the Integration

Ensure your Laravel application is running and publicly accessible.
Send a test message to your WhatsApp number and check if the message details are being stored in your Google Sheet.

This is just an idea of how you can implement it.
